# Tomcat8 searches localized JARs

Tags: linux, web-services, localization, tomcat8

I've got some Webservices working in a Tomcat8 on Linux.  I've put the following jars in /usr/share/tomcat8/lib

```
/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/webservices-api.jar*
/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/webservices-extra-api.jar*
/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/webservices-extra.jar*
/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/webservices-rt.jar*
/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/webservices-tools.jar*
```

However, when starting up, Tomcat logs report things like

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat8/lib/webservices-rt_de.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat8/lib/webservices-rt_zw_TH.jar
```

....

My Webservices certainly are localized but what does that have to do with the name of a common jar like webservices-rt.jar ??? It is strange to me.

I've been googling right the error literally and things like "Tomcat searches localized libraries|jar" ...but nothing found at the moment :(

Comment: OK ! Quite Strange but this trial to locate localized JAR files it only happens when I put those JARs (webservices-rt.jar) in /usr/share/tomcat8/lib. But if I move the webservices-rt.jar to myapp/WEB-INF/lib the WARNING dissapears!!! WTH!?!?